# Convert symbols using ToUnicode CMaps

Tags: pdf, text, unicode, replace

I'm parsing PDF file. I decoded all streams, got text from text objects and ToUnicode CMaps. But I don't know, when do I need replace symbols from text to symbols(strings) from ToUnicode CMaps.

When I see some like <01239099> I use this convert table and all is OK. But some files need, that I use convert table, while parsing simple text like
[(.&)-2(.K)-5(.D)-8(.S)], then all is OK too.

Does somebody know rule, which symbols need replace using convert table?

Comment: *Does somebody know rule, which simbols need replace using convert table?* - If you do text extraction and have a **ToUnicode** table for some font, you should always use it.

Comment: @mkl May I build one ToUnicode table like dictionary <oldSymbol, newSymbol>, consist of ToUnicode tables in stream? Or Do I have to use one table for each fonts?

Comment: Different fonts may have different ToUnicode mappings for the same glyph identifier, in some font 65 may map to "A", in some other to "Z". Thus, you have to use a separate table for each font.